# jQuery UI Versions and Themes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Are the CSS and image files in a jQuery theme dependent on the version of the jQueryUI?  If I were to upgrade from jQueryUI v1.8.* to v1.9* to v1.10*, would I need a seperate set of theme files?

Comment: Any particular reason you would _not_ want your versioned files to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, if a certain component (E.g. Widgets > Dialog) has been updated significantly then some of the functionality link between that updated component and the CSS file is either partially lost to a point where it doesn't work as intended or lost entirely.

In saying that, I messed around with this in a recent project and ended up running the v1.9.2 CSS on the latest 1.10.2 jQueryUI with no issues whatsoever.